# Merge two strings in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have been trying to figure out the right way to approach this problem but didn't had any success yet. The problem is I have two variables- one contains the server+site root path and the second contains the path to a file like-

```
<xsl:variable name="a">/user/folder/academics/aps/includes</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="b">/aps/includes/something/test.html</xsl:variable>
```

What I'm trying to do here is apply a function to both these strings so that the end result will look like-

```
/user/folder/academics/aps/includes/something/test.html
```

What I have tried so far is tokenize() the string and then compare each item but the problem with that is if let's say folder name "academics" repeat twice, it stops at the first one. I'm sure there is a better way to approach this problem. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: For your benefit as well as for those who might help you with the XSLT, you should more clearly define the intended merger.  Providing a mere single case leaves way too much unspecified.

Comment: I don't think this problem is *well-defined*. There are more than one possible solutions, with no way to determine which one is correct. What if the *real* path to the file is `/user/folder/academics/aps/includes/includes/something/test.html?`

Comment: I agree, can't be done. Simple example. Part "a" is /foo/bar/foo/bar and Part "b" is /foo/bar/x.html. What is the correct answer ? is it /foo/bar/x.html or is it /foo/bar/foo/bar/x.html?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added more examples but the solution by @michael.hor257k was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to assume that the *longest* overlap between the two paths is a common part, then something like this could work for you:

```
<xsl:template name="merge-paths">
    <xsl:param name="path1"/>
    <xsl:param name="path2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="root2" select="concat('/', substring-before(substring-after($path2, '/'), '/'), '/')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($path1, $root2)">
            <xsl:variable name="tail1" select="concat($root2, substring-after($path1, $root2))" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with($path2, $tail1)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$path1"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($path2, $tail1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($path1, $root2)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($root2, 1, string-length($root2) - 1)"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="merge-paths">
                        <xsl:with-param name="path1" select="concat('/', substring-after($path1, $root2))"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="path2" select="$path2"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($path1, 1, string-length($path1) - 1)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$path2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

Here are some examples of calling the template and the resulting output:

**1. No overlap:**

```
    <xsl:call-template name="merge-paths">
        <xsl:with-param name="path1">/a/b/c/</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="path2">/d/e/f.html</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

`<result>/a/b/c/d/e/f.html</result>`

**2. Simple overlap:**

```
    <xsl:call-template name="merge-paths">
        <xsl:with-param name="path1">/a/b/c/d/</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="path2">/c/d/e/f.html</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

`<result>/a/b/c/d/e/f.html</result>`

**3. Double overlap:**

```
    <xsl:call-template name="merge-paths">
        <xsl:with-param name="path1">/a/b/c/d/c/d/</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="path2">/c/d/e/f.html</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

`<result>/a/b/c/d/c/d/e/f.html</result>`

**4. False overlap:**

```
    <xsl:call-template name="merge-paths">
        <xsl:with-param name="path1">/a/b/c/d/x/</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="path2">/c/d/e/f.html</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
```

`<result>/a/b/c/d/x/c/d/e/f.html</result>`

Note the presence of closing slash at the end of path1.
This is actually an XSLT 1.0 solution; there may be better ways to implement this in later versions (regex?).

Comment: Helpful in XSLT implementation as well as in fleshing out requirements.  Nice answer.  +1

Comment: +1 for prividing answers which could go into XSLT textbooks right away.